# python TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, queue, typeerror, priority-queue

I keep getting: `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'` on line 40 code is below when I print the values in the while statement they come back as ints:

```py
pQueue = [['A', 4], ['B', 15], ['A', 15], ['A', 12]]

class priorityQueue():
    def __init__(self,queue):
        self.queue = queue

    def sort(self):
        length = len(self.queue)
        tempListA = []
        tempListB = []
        tempListC = []

        # splice the list depending if the letter is a b or c 
        for i in range(0, length):
            tempItem = self.queue[i]
            if tempItem[0] == 'A':
                tempListA.append(tempItem)
                
            elif tempItem[0] == 'B':
                tempListB.append(tempItem)
                
            elif tempItem[0] == 'C':
                tempListC.append(tempItem)
                
        #sort each list via number in positon
        for i in range(0, len(tempListA)):
            valueA = tempListA[i]
            
            currentValueA = valueA[1]
            
            positonA = i
            
            a=tempListA[positonA-1]
            
            b=a[1]
            

            while (positonA>0) and (b>currentValueA):
                tempListA[positonA]=tempListA[positonA-1]
                positonA = [positonA-1]

            tempListA[positonA]=valueA

            print(tempListA)


        #sort each list via number in positon
        for i in range(0, len(tempListB)):
            valueB = tempListB[i]
            
            currentValueB = valueB[1]
            
            positonB = i
            
            a=tempListB[positonB-1]
            
            b=a[1]
            

            while (positonB>0) and (b>currentValueB):
                tempListB[positonB]=tempListB[positonB-1]
                positonB = [positonB-1]

            tempListB[positonB]=valueB

            print(tempListB)
        
        #sort each list via number in positon for c
        for i in range(0, len(tempListC)):
            valueC = tempListC[i]
            
            currentValueC = valueC[1]
            
            positonC = i
            
            a=tempListC[positonC-1]
            
            b=a[1]
            

            while (positonC>0) and (b>currentValueC):
                tempListC[positonC]=tempListC[positonC-1]
                positonC = [positonC-1]

            tempListC[positonC]=valueC

            print(tempListC)

        # merge the lists back together
        mergedQ = []
        for i in range(0, len(tempListA)):            
            a = tempListA[i]
            mergedQ.append(a)
            print(mergedQ)

        for i in range(0, len(tempListB)):            
            a = tempListB[i]
            mergedQ.append(a)
            print(mergedQ)

        for i in range(0, len(tempListC)):            
            a = tempListC[i]
            mergedQ.append(a)
            print(mergedQ)
                       
        
a = priorityQueue(pQueue)
a.sort()
```

The *actual* output with the above code is:

```
[['A', 4], ['A', 15], ['A', 12]]
[['A', 4], ['A', 15], ['A', 12]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "66737040.py", line 108, in <module>
    a.sort()
  File "66737040.py", line 38, in sort
    while (positonA>0) and (b>currentValueA):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: could you highlight the line that is throwing the error

Comment: or even reduce your code to a [mre]

Comment: You've got mismatched levels of indirection.  `valueA` is a single entry (a list of two items), but `b` is one of the numbers in one of those entries.

Comment: are you sure you can't just do `self.queue.sort()`?  If the goal is to implement your own sorting from scratch, I'd recommend doing some reading on sorting algorithms and starting over -- it's going to be very hard to get this code working as-is, and with a fresh start I think you could implement a simple sort in about ten lines.

Comment: It was a issue with the square brackets on line 41 and the priority queue has to split to sort it by the letter and number